# HTTP Status 404 After refresh

Tags: apache, .htaccess, single-page-application

I develop web app  using angular 7. When I deploy and put in Apache Web Server. It can't refresh. When refresh it got error http status 404. I've put `.htaccess` same folder with angular app but still same. This is my url `http://localhost:8080/home`

I don't know what to do to make it work.

`.htaccess` code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the solution..

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
],
providers:[{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```